# Testing a string or char for upper, lower case and numbers C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm trying out an exercise where I have the user write a pass and I have to check the pass for length (must be at least 6 characters), upper case, lower case, and at least 1 number. for some reason, when I try to make it work, it wont detect both upper case and lowercase. even when "lower" or "upper" are == true, it still goes to the nested if (!lower) or if (!upper) conditional and runs that code block when the other is false.

can anyone show me where the logic is wrong? I'm not understanding why its even accessing an if with it false if the bool variable is set to true.

```
 bool verified(const char *pass)
 {
     int length = strlen(pass);
     bool lower, upper, number;
     lower = hasLower(pass);
     upper = hasUpper(pass);
     number = hasNumber(pass);
     if (length < 6)
     {
         cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain enough characters";
         return false;
     }
     else
     {
         if (lower && upper && number)
         {
             cout << "Your pass is valid and verified. Congrats!";
             return true;
         }
         if (!lower)
         {
             if (!number)
             {
                 cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain lower case letters or at least 1 number";
                 return false;
             }
             if (!upper);
             {
                 cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain lower case or upper case letters";
                 return false;
             }
             cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain lower case letters";
             return false;
         }
         if (!upper);
         {
             if (!number)
             {
                 cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain upper case letters or at least 1 number";
                 return false;
             }
             if (!lower);
             {
                cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain upper case or lower case letters"1;
                return false;
             }
             cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain upper case letters";
             return false;
         }
         if (!number)
         {
             cout << "INVALID: Your pass does not contain at least 1 number";
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

method for checking upper case

```
 bool hasUpper(const char *pass)
 {
     bool upper;
     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pass); i++)
     {
         upper = isupper(pass[i]);
         if (upper == true)
         {
             return true;
             break;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

method for checking lower case

```
 bool hasLower(const char *pass)
 {
     bool lower;
     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pass); i++)
     {
         lower = islower(pass[i]);
         if (lower == true)
         {
             return true;
             break;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

method for checking for number

```
 bool hasNumber(string pass)
 {
     if (pass.find('0') != string::npos ||
         pass.find('1') != string::npos ||
         pass.find('2') != string::npos || 
         pass.find('3') != string::npos || 
         pass.find('4') != string::npos || 
         pass.find('5') != string::npos || 
         pass.find('6') != string::npos ||
         pass.find('7') != string::npos || 
         pass.find('8') != string::npos ||
         pass.find('9') != string::npos)
         return true;
     else
         return false;
 }
```

Comment: Which one does it go into, how do you know it is true?

Comment: `return true; break;` the break is unreachable - bad style.

Comment: A concrete test example would help. Is the problem with `verified("Ab")`? What happens, what should happen?

Comment: Use `std::isdigit` to test whether a character is a digit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isdigit/

Comment: Or `find_first_of("0123456789")`

Comment: You dont need `break` in ur `hasUpper` and `hasLower` functions as was pointed out. You also dont need to do `if (lower == true)`, just `if(lower)` will do

Comment: if lower == true and upper == false, then it goes into if (!upper) first, then the nested if (!lower) even though upper == true. I know its true by calling the method at the beginning. my input varies, I've been trying all caps or all lowercase to test the different conditions.

Comment: Why use two versions `const char *pass` and `string pass`?

Comment: I executed your code with "abCde1", "abcde1" .. the outputs were correct.

Comment: @RakibulHasan when I run "abcde1" i am not getting the correct output - it says that i am not using upper or lower case but I am obviously using lower case. it went into if (!upper) then into if (!lower) but lower was true.

Comment: Could you please show how you call your function ? Is there any cast on the argument ?

Comment: @Qassim char pass[20]; cin >> pass; char *passPtr = pass; while (!verified(pass)) { cout << "\nEnter a password that contains at least 6 charcters, \n" << "an uppercase and a lowercase letter, and a number: "; cin >> pass; }

Comment: BTW if the aim is learning algorithmic, ok. But if the aim is learning C++, please consider using `std::any_of` and `std::isupper/islower/isdigit`. `verified` can be written with only three call to the `any_of` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written this:

> `if (!upper) *;*`

You see the `;` after it??

Infact, you have done this in multiple locations in your code.

Comment: thanks for the tip on that. I changed both lower/upper to your suggested code (respectively).

Comment: Though this is a poor practice in term of readability and code quality to implicitly convert from int to bool (as said in the link you provide), it is a fully defined behavior. So it does not explain the bug. I don't think changing to `int` being a good idea since the variale are semantically boolean.

Comment: @jacksonSD: the actual issue seems to be a very very trivial one. Just the case of a (few) stray `;`!

Comment: @Sinstein This was it. Thanks so much for catching that. I hate when its something trivial. at least you taught me a bit on bool int conversion issues and im reading up on any_of. glad to learn from it. thanks!

Comment: @jacksonSD All of us hate it when its something trivial, yet no one is looking to find a trivial mistake :P. Glad I could help.